# Magento: Shopping cart rules yield unwanted behaviour

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, discount

I'm trying to implement the following price rule in Magento:

For products of a certain brand XXX the next discounts should be applied (EDIT: subselections with different products may also be made):

- 3.99 a piece
- n x 8 pieces for n x 3.99 (e.g. for 5 pieces no discount is applied and the customer pays 5 x 3.99, but for, say, 10 pieces he will pay 3.99 + 2 x 3.99 since it's 8 + 2 pieces)
- n x 13 pieces for n x 5.99
- n x 38 pieces for n x 14.99

I have tried to implement this using shopping cart price rule options with [this Amasty extension](http://amasty.com/media/user_guides/special_promotions_user_guide.pdf) in Magento, however, I ran into some problems because Magento applies these discounts in an unwanted way.

**What did I do?**

I have split this discount into 3 price rules: one rule for n x 8 pieces, one for n x 13 and one for n x 38. Then I implemented each rule using the "Each group of N for fixed price" option. Now separately, these rules work fine, e.g. when ONLY the n x 8 rule is active and I toss 16 products in the shopping cart, I pay only 2 x 3.99. However, when all these rules are active and my cart is filled with 16 products, Magento makes me pay only $1, while the price I want customers to pay is again 2 x 3.99. By the way, how Magento amounts to $1 is unclear to me.

**Possible solutions (?)**

I know there are options like setting priority and stopping the execution of further rules, but that does not seem to help. Moreover, stopping rules is sometimes not the wanted behaviour. Say I have 46 pieces (38 + 8) in my cart. Then I want customers to pay 14.99 + 3.99. "Stop executing further rules" would make you pay 14.99 + 8 x 3.99 (intuitively, I have not tested this).

Does anybody know if it's possible to implement this discount? And if not, what's the closest I can get? You have my thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate all active rules than debug one by one set rule with priority ,

Also check rule condition , tax , customer group , grand total , shipping address etc...